# Rack (Sinatra) App pointing '/' to parent's root when deployed in subfolder

Tags: apache, sinatra, rack, passenger

I have a bunch of small sinatra apps, and now I have to publish them under SSL HTTP as well.

I have https://secure.mydomain.com/ and I want to publish those apps in subdirectories:

- /app1
- /app2

I followed Phusion Passenger instructions [here](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#deploying_rack_to_sub_uri) to publish in subdirs, but inside each application '/' points to root directory.

I don't want to change the code of all apps because, they are already working in non-ssl environment.

What do I need to change to make my application's '/' point to app's root, and not parent's root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just need the [`url` helper method](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Generating%20URLs):

```
url '/' # => https://secure.mydomain.com/app1/
```

Comment: Thanks. Had a lot of work inserting the helper, but that did the job.